# Javascript app, with elemens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on this project where i need to make a site with sticky notes that can change color, get deleted, get resized and move around and be ablo to move over other notes.

i've been falling back lately. Used so many hours on "basic" functions that won't work and now im here!

So i want to hear if someone could help med with:

Getting the onclick function to work! I need to hide the Jscolor changer
Getting a element deleted when clicking on the delete button.
And when adding a new Note/sticker the Jscolor does work.

When i run the site the first note i get it can change the color, but when i add a new i cant i want to find a solution for that

I hope anyone can helt me. And the guys that can help me with all the this will get something from me :)

Check the code
http://codepen.io/Qbinx/pen/OmObRg

```
    <p class="half-circle">
    <button class="addNoteBtn">
        <i class="ion-android-add-circle"></i>
    </button>
</p>    


<script src="jscolor.js"></script>  



<!--<div class="sticker" id="rect">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <button class="color" onclick="colorpicker"><i class="ion-android-color-palette"></i></button>
    <button class="deleteBtn" onclick="deleteaction"><i class="ion-android-delete"></i></button>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <input class="jscolor" onchange="update(this.jscolor)" value="cc66ff">
</div>-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    function update(jscolor) {
        document.getElementById('rect').style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor;
}
</script>
```

Comment: don't use id (only one unique id per site should be there), but create someting more personal which counts for the single note only

Comment: @icepickle What can that be for instance? I'm still new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function update(jscolor) {
        document.getElementById('rect').style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor;
}
</script>
```

You are calling `getElementById()`. There can only be one unique ID.

Basically what I'm trying to say is:

You have 1 rectangle. Rec 1. You can change it's color because the ID is `rect`. When you create a new rectangle, you can't assign the ID called `rect` again because when you call `getElementById()`, it will only get one element with that ID and it will be the first one that you created which is Rect 1.

Each rectangle ID needs to be unique. When you call the color picker, you need to `getElementById()` of the unique rectangle.

Comment: backgroundColor is invalid, use background

Comment: @IlyasKabirov Yes, there is `background-color`. But since he is changing the style using JavaScript, he needs to use `backgroundColor` which means the same thing as `background-color`.

Comment: arhh i get the point, and i didn't know that before. So is there a function that can increase or change the name to like rect1, rect1 and so on? Or no i need to find a other solution?

Comment: @UsamaAhmed You can use a for loop to do that.

Comment: @UsamaAhmed Please accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: @Edward You didnt really help, other than saying i could do it with a loop. Iøm still not sure about how to use a loop to do this, because when you create a loop you gotta set how many times you want it to loop though. You get me? And when thats said when im using the document.getElementById how do i put those numbers in?